# How can I merge or join these table(seg, conv)? [cloesed]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two table like these.

[image: First table is SEG]

[image: Second table is CONV]

I have to merge or join these two table like this.(on 'id', 'date')

[image: Result_merge]

How do I combine to get the same result as the third(in PYTHON)?
Please help me and always thx.

- Google Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kFpKdzYi8GVfGHfDEyO9OnfzZeDr6tN8dNUL76mZ4VI/edit#gid=1661729794

Comment: pivot the second table and merge (see duplicates). NB. please do not use images of data, provide **text** or **DataFrame constructors**

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kFpKdzYi8GVfGHfDEyO9OnfzZeDr6tN8dNUL76mZ4VI/edit#gid=1661729794 
its google spread sheet data.
Could u help me?